# Mostrar una lista de items en un campo de una consulta SQL (Relación Muchos a Muchos)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hola cuento con tres tablas una de Registro de un visitante, la segunda en la cual enlazo el registro del visitante con los artículos que ingreso, y en la tercera tengo los datos de los artículos registrados a nombre del visitante.

[image: Estructura de las tablas]
Lo que me gustaría es que en un campo de la consulta me aparecieran en listados todos los artículos que ingreso (los de la lista de artículos).

Ejemplo.
[PKRegistro] = {ID}

[FKVisitante] = {ID}

[Lista de Articulos] = {

- Articulo 1
- Articulo 2
- Etc....

}

**He Intentado con esto**

```
SELECT RV.[PKRegisterVisitID]
      ,RV.FKVisitorID                 
      ,ListE.[FKElectronicEquipmentID]
      ,(EE.[Brand]+' '+EE.[Model]+' '+EE.[SerialNumber]) AS ElectronicEquipment  
  FROM [GPSecurityCheckin].[dbo].[SC_RegisterVisit] RV (NOLOCK)         
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SC_ListElectronicEquipment] ListE (NOLOCK) ON ListE.[FKRegisterVisitID] = RV.PKRegisterVisitID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CT_ElectronicEquipmentVisitor] EE (NOLOCK) ON ListE.[FKElectronicEquipmentID] = EE.[PKElectronicEquipmentID]
```

Pero me arroja los datos de esta manera, me gustaría que se mostrara en una sola columna.
[image: Dato Arrogado]

**Busco**

```
 PKRegistro  PKVisitante   PKArticulos  Articulos
-----------------------------------------------------
     1           1            NULL         NULL
     2           1            NULL         NULL
     3           1            1 2    Articulo 1, Articulo 2
     4           1            NULL         NULL
```

Comment: Qué has intentado? En qué estás atorado?

Comment: Me atore con la lógica, no se me ocurre mas que hacer un LEFT JOIN del LEFT JOIN, pero eso solo me traera un dato, u.u

Comment: No se puede mostrar una lista de datos en una consulta SQL. Las bases de datos no funcionan asi. Si estas tratando de solucionar un problema de tu vista haciendo esto, vas por mal camino. Las bases de datos procesan las filas una a una, y devuelven una fila por fila procesada. no devuelven una lista. Podrias tratar de armar un json o xml en un campo, pero no se si es algo recomendable en todos los casos. Y hay que ver, si vale la pena.

Comment: por favor postea un ejemplo del resultado que quieres. Pareciera que estás usando SQL Server, quita el tag de MySQL y pon la versión de SQL Server que estás usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo tener algo que te puede ayudar Furiduri. Ahi te va, como veo que estas usando "(NOLOCK)" quiero creer que no ocupare explicar mucho.

```
SELECT RV.[PKRegisterVisitID]
      ,RV.FKVisitorID                 
      ,temp.PKArticulos
      ,temp.Articulos
FROM [GPSecurityCheckin].[dbo].[SC_RegisterVisit] RV (NOLOCK)         
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t1.PKRegisterVisitID,
            STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(255), t2.[FKElectronicEquipmentID]) 
                FROM [dbo].[SC_ListElectronicEquipment] t2 (NOLOCK)
                WHERE t2.[FKRegisterVisitID] = t1.PKRegisterVisitID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS PKArticulos,
            STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(255), (t4.[Brand]+' '+t4.[Model]+' '+t4.[SerialNumber])) 
                FROM [dbo].[SC_ListElectronicEquipment] t3 (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CT_ElectronicEquipmentVisitor] t4 (NOLOCK) ON t1.[FKElectronicEquipmentID] = t2.[PKElectronicEquipmentID]
                WHERE t3.[FKRegisterVisitID] = t1.PKRegisterVisitID
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Articulos  
        FROM [GPSecurityCheckin].[dbo].[SC_RegisterVisit] t1
    ) temp on temp.PKRegisterVisitID = RV.PKRegisterVisitID
```

No estoy seguro si funcione tal cual, puede que tenga errorsitos pero creo que te doy un muy buena idea amigo, minimo con lo que te puedas apoyar para seguir buscando. De echo te dejo aqui un [enlace](http://chancrovsky.blogspot.com/2013/04/concatenar-usando-for-xml-path-y-stuff.html) donde puedes profundizar un poco mas del tema y ver como y porque funciona el **STUFF**.

**OJO!! Recomendado** todo el LEFT JOIN que puse meterlo en una tabla temporal para darle mas orden y mejor rendimiento. Quedando algo asi la idea:

```
SELECT t1.PKRegisterVisitID,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(255), t2.[FKElectronicEquipmentID]) 
        FROM [dbo].[SC_ListElectronicEquipment] t2 (NOLOCK)
        WHERE t2.[FKRegisterVisitID] = t1.PKRegisterVisitID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS PKArticulos,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(255), (t4.[Brand]+' '+t4.[Model]+' '+t4.[SerialNumber])) 
        FROM [dbo].[SC_ListElectronicEquipment] t3 (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[CT_ElectronicEquipmentVisitor] t4 (NOLOCK) ON t1.[FKElectronicEquipmentID] = t2.[PKElectronicEquipmentID]
        WHERE t3.[FKRegisterVisitID] = t1.PKRegisterVisitID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Articulos
INTO #temp 
FROM [GPSecurityCheckin].[dbo].[SC_RegisterVisit] t1

SELECT RV.[PKRegisterVisitID]
      ,RV.FKVisitorID                 
      ,temp.PKArticulos
      ,temp.Articulos
FROM [GPSecurityCheckin].[dbo].[SC_RegisterVisit] RV (NOLOCK)         
    LEFT JOIN #temp temp on temp.PKRegisterVisitID = RV.PKRegisterVisitID
```

Saludos y espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Hola @Furiduri podrías hacer un INNER JOIN de las 3 tablas, más o menos así, si en caso no es la respuesta, envía un ejemplo más claro:

```
SELECT   
        AV.ITEM,
        AV.ID_ARTCULO,
        A.NOMBRE_ARTICULO, -- SI HUBIERA EL CAMPO
        AV.ID_REGISTRO,
        V.NOMBRE_VISITANTE  -- SI HUBIERA EL CAMPO

FROM TBL_ART_VIS AV
    INNER JOIN TBL_ARTICULO A ON A.ID_ARTICULO = AV.ID_ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN TBL_VISITAMTE V ON V.ID_VISITANTE = AV.REGISTRO
```

Comment: En teoria es correcto, pero muestra solo un dato, u.u lo que busco es que me muestre en el campo [A.Nombre_Articulo], todos los articulos que estén en "Lista de Articulos Ingresados".

Comment: Has probado usando **LEFT JOIN** o **RIGHT JOIN**  ??

Comment: Si, ya le agregue mas contexto a la pregunta.